# how to show data on select from a dropdown in index page in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In the index page I have a select option. If I select a user from drop down it will show only that user's article list. In database I have two table called "articles" and "profiles". Now how can I show data on click from drop down in cakephp version 3? 
[Index Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDcmo.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Actually I'm new to cakephp framework. So I can't understand how to do it. I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: you should do ajax.

Comment: Then first create database and then use value of dropdown in your query to fetch your artical.

Comment: `Jquery datatables` can work for you. If you want want to use ajax

Comment: add a new action to your articles controller `getUserArticles($id)` then use jquery to make an asynchronous call to your action through 'GET /articles/get-user-articles/{$id}` request.. Read up on how to use jquery for ajax here `http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/`, give it a go and then comeback to us with any further questions if you come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following code to my project

```
<!-- controller -->
    <?php 
    public function index($user_id=null){
            if($this->request->is(['post'])){
                return $this->redirect(['action'=>'index', $this->request->data['user_id']]);
            }
            $this->loadModel('Users');
            $users = $this->Users->find('list');
            $articles = $this->Articles->find('all', ['conditions' => ['Articles.user_id'=>$user_id,]]);
            $this->set(compact('user_id', 'articles', 'users'));        
        }
     ?>

<!-- view[index.ctp] -->
 <?php echo $this->Form->create(null); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['empty'=>'Select', 'options'=>$users, 'value'=>$user_id]); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Go'), ['class'=>'btn-success']); ?>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
<div>
<?php
foreach($articles as $article){
    echo $article['title'].'<br>';
}
?>
</div>
```